# How to disable some php extensions pre-installed and enabled on Google App Engine container

Tags: php, google-app-engine

These extensions are pre-installed and enabled on Google App Engine php container:

- APCu
- Bzip2
- cURL
- FPM
- GMP
- mbstring
- mcrypt
- libsodium
- Memcached
- MySQL(PDO) (uses mysqlnd)
- MySQLi (uses mysqlnd)
- OPcache
- OpenSSL
- pcntl
- PostgreSQL
- PostgreSQL (PDO)
- Readline
- recode
- sem
- Sockets
- Zip
- Zlib

They are compiled with php and enabled by default (as you can see here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docker/blob/master/package-builder/debian/rules.in)

How can I disable some of then? MySQL for example, as I'm using postgres.

Here is my Dockerfile until the moment:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php72:latest

ARG ENABLE_XDEBUG
ARG COMPOSER_FLAGS='--no-scripts --no-dev --prefer-dist'
ENV COMPOSER_FLAGS=${COMPOSER_FLAGS}

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install unzip -y
RUN apt-get install autoconf -y
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y

# php-decimal
RUN apt-get install libmpdec-dev -y
RUN pecl install decimal

# Swoole
RUN pecl install swoole-4.2.13

COPY . $APP_DIR
RUN chown -R www-data.www-data $APP_DIR
RUN /bin/bash /build-scripts/move-config-files.sh
RUN /build-scripts/composer.sh;

ENTRYPOINT ["/build-scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]

# Option to install xdebug
RUN echo "Will enable XDEBUG: $ENABLE_XDEBUG"
RUN if [ "$ENABLE_XDEBUG" = "true" ]; then pecl install xdebug; fi
RUN if [ "$ENABLE_XDEBUG" = "true" ]; then echo "zend_extension=/opt/php72/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so" >> /opt/php72/lib/php.ini; fi

EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take complete control of the container and the extensions that are being loaded by mounting your own `php.ini` (and complete `conf.d` directory for that matter) into the container.

You can start the container and then log into the container by using...

```
docker exec -it [container_name] bash
```

...and navigate to the `/opt/php72/lib` directory. That, or download the `php.ini` directly using...

```
docker cp [container_name]:/opt/php72/lib/php.ini
```

...,modify it and volume mount it into the container using a `-v` flag or add it to a docker-compose.yml file.

Just one other thing that caught my attention in your Dockerfile is that the xdebug. So is added to the `php.ini`. It would be better to add a separate `.ini` to PHP's `conf.d` directory so the original file remains...well, original.